# CRUD in react-redux, showing post details from enother page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new in react-redux, and have a problem with state managment i think. I want to get post details from main table on home page, to show post details in details page...When i click on button details i change a path "/details/1, and i want to show post deteils with id=1. i get {post: undefined, getDetails: ƒ}

action.js

```
export const postDetails = (data, id) => ({
        type: "POST_DETAILS",
        post: data,
        id: id
})
```

reducer.js

```
case "POST_DETAILS":
    return state.posts.map((post) => {
        if(post.id === action.id) {
            return {
                ...post,
                post: post
            }
        } 
    })
```

container- GetDetails.js

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ post: state.post });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getDetails: (data, id) => dispatch(postDetails(data, id))
    };
};


const GetDetails = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Details)


export default GetDetails;
```

component-Details.js

```
class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getDetails(this.props.post, this.props.id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Details page
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        {this.props.post}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: Your reducer looks suspect. What is the state of your reducer before the action dispatch?

Comment: case "FETCH_POSTS":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                posts: []
            }
        case "FETCH_FAILD": 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                posts: []
            }
        case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                posts: action.posts
            }

Comment: state is array of posts...{posts: Array(100), loading: false}

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer is decimating its own state until state becomes undefined. You are starting with a state that is an object, but you are returning only one field of that object.

Starting with a state like this:

```
{
  loading: false,
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1
      post: 'foo',
      author: 'bar'
    },
    {
      id: 2
      post: 'fooz',
      author: 'barz'
    }
  ]
}
```

Dispatching an action like this:

```
{
  type: "POST_DETAILS",
  id: 1,
  post: 'this is never accessed'
}
```

will result in an **array**

```
[
  {
    id: 1
    post: {
      id: 1
      post: 'foo',
      author: 'bar'
    },
    author: 'bar'
  },
  undefined
]
```

Dispatching the action again will result in the state being `undefined`.

A third time will result in an error.

In your reducer, you probably meant to do something like this instead.

```
case "POST_DETAILS":
    return { ...state, posts: state.posts.map((post) => {
          if(post.id === action.id) {
              return {
                  ...post,
                  post: action.post
              }
          } else {
              return post
          }
      })
    }
```

Comment: tnx, great explanation. I changed my reducer but still nothing... what do you think about component Details.js and componetDidMount()? Do i need do call method with parameters this.props.posts and this.props.id?

Comment: No, since you are using the route parameters, you need look for them in this.props.params, not this.props.

Comment: Are you sure you're including your reducer in combineReducers()?